# Sending data from AJAX to php script via button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So cut things short I'm trying to create a pop up update panel on my to-do website using an html button. Now I already have a login-register system and it displays different tables for each user via queries with MySQL.

Now these update buttons contain 'TaskId' values created when the task are generated via queries and these id will be used to query data to display on the pop-up panel. I wanted to use AJAX to pass that data, that when you click on the button, it pops up the panel then after it sends the value (which is the taskID) to the PHP script `dashboard.php`. However, the PHP script cant seem to recceive it.

So to diagnose it, I logged the value on the javascript file, and it was able to display the value of the TaskId. I checked the network in the dev tools and it was sending. I checked the names and syntaxes. However it still didnt work. NOTE: the files are on the same folder.

Heres the code for Task generation in the tables (dashboard.php)

```
<?php
//CHECKS IF USER HAS ANY ONGOING TASK, 
$todoQuery = "SELECT * FROM todo_tbl where user_id = '$userID'";
$toDo = mysqli_query($conn, $todoQuery);
if (mysqli_num_rows($toDo) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toDo)) {
        // Gets each row 
        $taskId = $row['task_id'];
        $taskName = $row['task_name'];
        $taskDate= $row['due_date'];
        $taskStatus = $row['task_status'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo   "<td> $taskName</td>";
        echo   "<td> $taskDate </td>";
        echo   "<td> $taskStatus </td>";
        echo  "<td><button class='updateBtn' value='$taskId'>Update</button></td>";
        echo  "<td><button class='deleteBtn' value='$taskId'>Delete</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Javascript Code (dashboard.js):

```
//using JQUERY
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Reveal Update Panel and AJAX request
    $('.updateBtn').click(function () {
        var updTaskId = $(this).val();
        console.log(updTaskId);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/try/to_do_Website/dashboard.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {updTaskId: updTaskId},
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle the response and perform any necessary actions
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('AJAX Error:', error);
            }
        });
    });
```

And finally here's the code in the same file that supposed to receive the data (dashboard.php):

```
<!--retrieves task id from ajax request above and displays it on the input boxes-->
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['updTaskId'])) {
    $updTaskId= $_POST['updTaskId'];
    echo $updTaskId;
    $viewQuery = "SELECT * FROM todo_tbl where task_id = '$updTaskId'";
    $view = mysqli_query($conn, $viewQuery);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($view);
    $updtaskName = $row['task_name'];
    $updtaskDate = $row['due_date'];
    $updtaskStatus = $row['task_status'];
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please change your queries to parameterized prepared statements which are resilient against SQL injection

Comment: Ill take note of that.

Comment: "*However it still didnt work*" - what does that mean, *exactly*?  The code you've shown will not actually show anything on the front end, even if it works.  How do you know it is not working, what have you observed?

Comment: if you look at the code above on the code that is supposed to receive the data "echo $updTaskId, " it is supposed to display on the page the ID that was sent from the Ajax request which is not working. I also used var_dump to no avail

Comment: I'll try again - the Javascript you've shown does not use or display anything the back end script does.  Any `echo`ing, `var_dump()`ing, etc, will not be visible on your page.  The AJAX `success()` callback does not use the output your PHP generates.  As I said - even if everything works, nothing will be shown or visible on your front end.  Or are you checking the server response in your browser's devtools?  Once more - what *exactly* have you observed that makes you think it is not working?

Answer (score -1):

Your JavaScript and PHP code seem mostly correct, but i suggest you to check:

1. Check Console for Errors
2. **Use Relative URL in AJAX Request:**

   - Since your files are in the same folder, you can use a relative URL in your AJAX request. Change the `url` parameter in your AJAX call to `'dashboard.php'` instead of the full URL.

   ```js
   $.ajax({
       url: 'dashboard.php', // Change the URL
       method: 'POST',
       data: { updTaskId: updTaskId },
       success: function(response) {
           // Handle the response and perform any necessary actions
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           console.log('AJAX Error:', error);
       }
   });
   ```
3. **Add Content-Type Header in AJAX Request:**

   - Explicitly set the `Content-Type` header to ensure that the server interprets the data correctly.

   ```js
   $.ajax({
       url: 'dashboard.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: { updTaskId: updTaskId },
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', // Add this line
       success: function(response) {
           // Handle the response and perform any necessary actions
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           console.log('AJAX Error:', error);
       }
   });
   ```
4. Debugging PHP Code:

   - Use `var_dump` or `echo` statements to debug the PHP code in `dashboard.php`. Make sure that the `if (isset($_POST['updTaskId']))` condition is being satisfied.

Comment: additionally, it might help by entering: dataType: 'text'

Comment: No errors in the console did the numbers 2-3 to no avail, and it seems that the condition of the if statement isn't being satisfied